# How to get TCP connection ids of all connected clients in c# console application

Tags: c#, tcpclient, tcp, tcplistener

How can i get TCP Connection ID of all the connected clients.Actually i am making a program in c# (console application) that will return array with Connection Ids and IMEIs of connected clients. below code is simple client and server program so how can i get Connection id ?

Client Program :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text; 
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO; 
using System.Net.Sockets; 

namespace TcpEchoClient
{
    class TcpEchoClient
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "TCP Client";
            String server = "xxx.xxx.x.xx"; // IP address
            byte[] byteBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Test Message"); 
            int servPort = 1;
            TcpClient client = null;
            NetworkStream netStream = null;  
            try
            {
                client = new TcpClient(server, servPort); 
                Console.WriteLine("Connected to server... sending echo string");
                netStream = client.GetStream();
                netStream.Write(byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.Length); 
                Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to server...", byteBuffer.Length);
                int totalBytesRcvd = 0; 
                int bytesRcvd = 0; 
                while (totalBytesRcvd < byteBuffer.Length) 
                {
                    if ((bytesRcvd = netStream.Read(byteBuffer, totalBytesRcvd, byteBuffer.Length - totalBytesRcvd)) == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Connection closed prematurely.");
                        break;
                    }
                    totalBytesRcvd += bytesRcvd;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Received {0} bytes from server: {1}", totalBytesRcvd, Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteBuffer, 0, totalBytesRcvd));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                netStream.Close();
                client.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Server Program :

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
sing System.Net; 
using System.Net.Sockets;  

namespace TcpEchoServer
{
    class TcpEchoServer
    {
        private const int BUFSIZE = 32; 

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "TCP Server";
                int servPort = 1;
                TcpListener listener = null;
                try 
                {
                    listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any,servPort);
                    listener.Start();
                }
                catch(SocketException se)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(se.ErrorCode + ": " + se.Message);
                    Environment.Exit(se.ErrorCode);
                }
                byte[] rcvBuffer = new byte[BUFSIZE]; 
                int bytesRcvd; 
                for (; ; ) 
                {
                    TcpClient client = null;
                    NetworkStream netStream = null;
                    try
                    {
                        client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                        netStream = client.GetStream();
                        Console.Write("Handling client - ");
                        int totalBytesEchoed = 0;
                        while ((bytesRcvd = netStream.Read(rcvBuffer,0,rcvBuffer.Length)) >0)
                        {
                            netStream.Write(rcvBuffer,0,bytesRcvd);
                            totalBytesEchoed += bytesRcvd;
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("echoed {0} bytes.", totalBytesEchoed);
                        netStream.Close();
                        client.Close();

                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                        netStream.Close();
                    }
                }
          }
    }
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for the remote IP as your ID? Or are you asking how to manage the flow of multiple client connections?  It sounds like you need to look at the socket's RemoteEndPoint.

Comment: your `TcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint` is unique. It's a combination of IP and Port.  btw, the LocalEndPoint.Port is unique

Comment: Have a List<TCPClient> in server.  Every time a new client connects add to the List<> object.  You can then extract the the endpoints of the clients from the list.